# JSON array – which is the appropriate syntax (both valid) for looping

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON data and I want to run a check to see if an element I've hovered on matches the name 'sports', or 'technology' etc and then grab the key 'text' and 'image' values. The issue I'm having is I can only seem to retrieve the indexs and not the 'sports' or 'technology' names to see if they match with another element.

I'm unsure if my JSON array is set up correctly for this but I can adjust as required.

Any thoughts?

```
[  
   {  
      "sports":{  
         "image":"",
         "text":"\u003Cp\u003EWe believe businesses that are people-focused and have a well-defined story are poised for success. That\u2019s why we bring together branding and ownable experience design for our clients. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing.\u003C\/p\u003E"
      }
   },
   {  
      "media---entertainment":{  
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      }
   },
   {  
      "lifestyle":{  
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      }
   },
   {  
      "technology":{  
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      }
   },
   {  
      "education":{  
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      }
   }
]
```

Would this be better?

```
[
   {
      "sports":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"\u003Cp\u003EWe believe businesses that are people-focused and have a well-defined story are poised for success. That\u2019s why we bring together branding and ownable experience design for our clients. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing.\u003C\/p\u003E"
      },
      "media---entertainment":{
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      },
      "lifestyle":{
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      },
      "technology":{
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      },
      "education":{
         "image":"",
         "text":""
      }
   }
]
```

The JSON is generated using PHP as follows:

```
$clientsSectorsArray = array();
foreach ($sectors as $sector) {
    $clientsSectorsArray[] = array(
        "{$sanitizer->pageName($sector->global_text)}" => array(
            "image" => "{$sector->global_image->url}",
            "text" => "{$sector->global_textarea}",
        )
    );
}
$clientsSectors = json_encode($clientsSectorsArray);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking or what the issue is.

Comment: `The issue I'm having is I can only seem to retrieve the indexs and not the 'sports' or 'technology' names to see if they match with another element.`  That code isn't in your question.  It's difficult to help with code we can't see, so can you add it to the question?

Comment: The second one would be easier to use within javascript

Comment: In the second one, there's no need for the array around the object. Just use the object.

Comment: I'm asking how can I loop through the JSON array by the words 'sports' or 'technology'...

Comment: If you use the second version, you don't need to loop. Just use `array[0]["sports"]`

Comment: And if you get rid of the array, it's just `obj["sports"]`

Comment: @Barmar But it's added when using json_encode in PHP to output my JSON and can't get rid of it

Comment: The PHP doesn't need to wrap it in another level of array. It should just be `array('sports' => ...)` rather than `array(array('sports' => ...))`

Comment: Thanks everyone but I don't know what the words are (sports etc) – I need to loop through them to see if they exist.

Comment: `variable = "sports"; obj[variable]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is a poor structure. An array of objects where each object has a different key is a poor design. But you can use it like this:

```
item = data.find(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] == searchString);
if (item) {
    image = item.image;
    text = item.text;
}
```

The second version is easier, since you can just use the search string as a dynamic property name.

```
item = data[0][searchString];
```

But you shouldn't wrap your data in the extra array level. You can create it like this:

```
$clientsSectorsArray = array();
foreach ($sectors as $sector) {
    $clientsSectorsArray[$sanitizer->pageName($sector->global_text)] = array(
        "image" => "{$sector->global_image->url}",
        "text" => "{$sector->global_textarea}",
        );
}
$clientsSectors = json_encode($clientsSectorsArray);
```

This will produce the JSON:

```
{
  "sports":{
     "image":"",
     "text":"\u003Cp\u003EWe believe businesses that are people-focused and have a well-defined story are poised for success. That\u2019s why we bring together branding and ownable experience design for our clients. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing.\u003C\/p\u003E"
  },
  "media---entertainment":{
     "image":"",
     "text":""
  },
  "lifestyle":{
     "image":"",
     "text":""
  },
  "technology":{
     "image":"",
     "text":""
  },
  "education":{
     "image":"",
     "text":""
  }
}
```

And then you would use JavaScript:

```
item = data[searchString];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated my question with how I built the JSON. I can't see a different way of doing this?

Comment: I've added how to create the JSON without the array wrapper.

Comment: Many thanks. I seem to get this error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Your PHP script is probably echoing something other than `echo $clientSectors;`

Comment: Use the Network tab of the console to see the full AJAX response, and you'll see something other than the JSON.

Comment: I fixed that. Great. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198316/discussion-between-john-the-painter-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample project to show you how easy it can be to use this kind of JSON:

https://jsfiddle.net/gwLyn7ja/

html:

```
<button>sports</button>
<button>media---entertainment</button>
<button>lifestyle</button>
<button>technology</button>
<button>education</button>
<button>health</button>

<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

javascript (w jquery):

```
const ob = {
      "sports":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"sports text"
      },
      "media---entertainment":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"media text"
      },
      "lifestyle":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"lifestyl text"
      },
      "technology":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"tech text"
      },
      "education":{
         "image":"",
         "text":"education text"
      }
   };

function getObText(key) {
  if (ob[key]) {
    return ob[key].text
  } else {
    return 'key not found';
  }
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
    const key = $(this).text();
    const txt = getObText(key);
    $('textarea').val(txt);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
// const data = ... (your JSON data)

const myDesiredMatches = ["sports", "technology"]
validResults = data.filter(elem => {
    for(let match of myDesiredMatches)
        if(!elem.hasOwnProperty(match))
            return false
    return true
})
```